# Android: how to use FragmentTransaction.add in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

So I am trying to add a fragment within a fragment, so I was told to change my Fragment Transaction variable to go from:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
```

to

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

However, I am not sure what Id I would use when I call ft.add();

previously I was using android.R.id.content. Is there a similar id I can use for a fragment, or which Id should I use to be able to add a new fragment from within my fragment.

Edit:

activity_mainfrag:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#EEEEEE"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    ...

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this to add fragment:

```
    FragmentTransaction ft = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    ft.replace(R.id.container_parent, fragment, fragment.getTagText());
    ft.addToBackStack(fragment.getTagText());
    ft.commit();
```

Comment: what would container_parent be?

Comment: the layout parent where you want to inflate the child fragment. ex framelayout etc

Comment: Would it matter if the fragment is apart of a swipe page view?

Comment: can you please elaborate on swipe page view?

Comment: Yeah, sorry not the proper name. It's classified as a tabbed activity, and the navigation style is swipe view if that clarifies it. And then I am trying to add/replace a fragment in one of the tabs

Comment: Technically it shouldn't matter but I can't say for sure I haven't used child fragments in tabbed manner

Comment: okay, so maybe I am understanding the Id wrong. So the fragment that is loaded inflates "activity_mainfrag" which contains the header edited in above.   So would that mean I would use "ft.replace(R.id.mainView, fragment, "myFragmentTag");"

Comment: well briefly main parent fragment is loaded in the layout of Activity, Then the child fragment is loaded in the layout of the parent fragment.